# Java based Http client to read response from non HTTP compliant server

Tags: java, http, httpclient, httpconnection

I am trying to connect to legacy HTTP server and it seems to be NOT complaint to HTTP protocol, when providing response. As I cannot change the server so looking a way to get around. I have tried

1. Apache client

   ```
   httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
   ```

   throws `ClientProtocolException` and `httpResponse` is null
2. HttpURLConnection

   ```
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream(),"UTF8"));
   ```

   throws  `java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response`

I am trying to avoid opening a plain socket connection. Any other ways to read non-compliant HTTP response from any java HTTP client?

Comment: Are you sure it's an HTTP server at all? How 'legacy' is 'legacy'? Can you browse to it? if so, can you provide the response headers?

Comment: @EJP Yes it is an HTTP server , i can see my HTTP request in server logs and i can see it is trying to return an xml but it is not setting the HTTP response headers

Comment: If it isn't sending HTTP response headers it isn't an HTTP server, and you can't use any form of HTTP client to access it. You haven't answered my last two questions.

Comment: I have got the same problem with a server that returns an empty header in every response.